# How to put a value from SQL number format column to a double in VB.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have selected from SQL like this

```
SELECT MAX(receivecount) FROM config
```

which shows only one value of 20161.
so now I can't take that number and put it in a double or a int32. The column name is ReceiveCount
Current what I have is this

```
        Dim ads2 As New DataTable
        strrs2 = "SELECT MAX(recievecount) FROM tblcmconfig"
        Using ads23 As OracleDataReader = GetDataReader(strrs2, CommandType.Text, ExecuteType.Execute)
            ads2.Load(ads23)
        End Using
        Dim dugaar As Double '= Convert.ToDouble(ids)
        dugaar = Double.Parse(ads2("recievecount").ToString)
```

After this I am trying to put that value in a `textedit.editvalue` as that `textedit` is numbers only enterable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your datatable is populated correctly. You either need to give the MAX(recievecount) a name in the select statement like:

```
MAX(recievecount) as rc
```

Then

```
Double.Parse(ads2(0)("rc").ToString)
```

Or you can refer to the row and and column numers:

```
Double.Parse(ads2(0)(0).ToString)
```